# Builder pattern vs named parameters vs abstract class

Tags: php, design-patterns

I am really confused if the builder pattern is anyway useful. Lets I have this builder:

```
<?php

interface VehicleBuilderInterface
{
    public function setDoors(): void;
    public function setWheels(): void;
    public function getVehicle(): Vehicle;
}

abstract class Vehicle
{
    /**
     * @var object[]
     */
    private $data;
    
    public function setParts(string $key, object $value)
    {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }
}

class Car extends Vehicle
{
}

class Truck extends Vehicle
{
}

class Door
{
}

class Wheel
{
}

class TruckBuilder implements VehicleBuilderInterface
{
    public function __construct(private Vehicle $truck)
    {
    }

    public function setDoors(): void
    {
        $this->truck->setParts('doors', new Door());
    }

    public function setWheels(): void
    {
        $this->truck->setParts('wheels', new Wheel());
    }

    public function getVehicle(): Vehicle
    {
        return $this->truck;
    }
}

class CarBuilder implements VehicleBuilderInterface
{
    public function __construct(private Vehicle $car)
    {
    }

    public function setDoors(): void
    {
        $this->car->setParts('doors', new Door());
    }

    public function setWheels(): void
    {
        $this->car->setParts('wheels', new Wheel());
    }

    public function getVehicle(): Vehicle
    {
        return $this->car;
    }
}

class Director
{
    public function build(VehicleBuilderInterface $vehicleBuilder): Vehicle
    {
        $vehicleBuilder->setDoors();
        $vehicleBuilder->setWheels();
        return $vehicleBuilder->getVehicle();
    }
}

$director = new Director;
$director->build(new CarBuilder());
```

Isn't it much easier to use named paramaters nowadays? Even before the named parameters, why not just creating 2 classes - Truck and Car, and just build one of it when I need it ? The builder above seems like a lot of coding and just trying to make things 'fancy'. What am I missing in this concept after red and watched ton of articles and videos. Will be very thankful for any clarification. Also what is the point of the private $data variable? Can't I just put the properties I need in the abstract class like:

```
abstract class Vehicle
{
    private Door $door;
    private Wheel $wheel;

    abstract public function setDoor(): void;
    abstract public function setWheel(): void;
    abstract public function getDoor(): Door;
    abstract public function getWheel(): Wheel;
}
```

This removes the need of builder interace, right? Maybe to summarize my question - why do we need to code so much when it can be made with half amount of code?

Comment: There are some more abstract things that lend them to the first pattern, I think. Basically, if you can envision code that consumes this object calling a `has` method. For instance, library code _could_ have a builder, have implementors build something, and the library consume. But generally, if you know your types ahead of time, I agree that concrete classes are way less code and easier to reason about.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thank you! Maybe I can't break my mind to see the usage of all these patterns. I literally can make things much easier and short without it actually and confuses me a lot.

Comment: Honestly, you might never see a valid case. I know I've personally done it in the past, but I can't really remember my specific need anymore, and for all I know my older self might have a better way with the newer language features.